# Android wallpaper changed periodically

Tags: android

I want set wallpaper.I have four options.By "Daily",by "day of week"(e.g >every Sunday ),by "week of the month" (e.g> 2nd week), by "monthly ".How is this possible.Can anyone  give some idea.Can anyone can help me??Can anyone give some sample code.

Thanks and Regards,
Md Maidul Islam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it.I create a tabview .Then I solve it